White square instead of pointer in 24.04
I have just updated to Ubuntu 24.04. In Gnome using the pointer DMZ-White, when the mouse is over the top bar or the dock/launcher, the mouse pointer is a light gray (almost white) square. I have tried changing the mouse icon in Tweaks and adding a symbolic link as per egmont's post here
This square instead of a pointer makes the GUI look very clunky and amateurish, how can I revert to having a nice pointer?

Try changing cursor styles using tweaks for me it works for some cursor styles like Yaru and Adwaita(default)
